# Bootstrap multiselect - to trigger event 'onSelectAll' or 'onDeselectAll' when De-select / Uncheck all options in a single click (best way needed)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, bootstrap-multiselect

I want to put a listener on 'onDeselectAll' event, but 'onDeselectAll' - does not exist in the latest version of the [Bootstrap multiselect](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect) plugin.

I want something like that

```
        $('.multiselect').multiselect({
            enableFiltering: true,
            enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
            includeSelectAllOption: true,
            includeSelectAllDivider: true,
            maxHeight: 400,
            onSelectAll: function () {
                console.log("select-all-nonreq");
            },
            onDeselectAll: function () {
                console.log("deselect-all-nonreq");
            }
        });
```

What is the best way to do that?

What is the best fork solving this issue? I found [this fork](http://gitlab.mmcs.sfedu.ru:82/dummer/itlabfork-bootstrap-multiselect/commit/2e93a99a5477b02d693105c3f34d480bee43fe08) not quite the same as 'onDeselectAll' but close. Is there anything better?

I red somewhere that this option existed in older versions, why did they remove it?

I've found the developers made an [issue](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/issues/752) about it. Does it mean they are planning to fix it? When?

I was checking if Select2 can do 'select all' is it possible?

What should I do? Wait, to go older version or use another fork use another plugin?

This is a desired result.

[image]

Comment: This bug is resolved in the new version. I have used it. so no need to implement any workaround.
https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/

Answer (score 2):

Your code is correct, these events already exist: http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#configuration-options-onSelectAll

But... There is a bug. I created a fork on this project to fix this bug... I've already made a pull request that is waiting for merge.

Pull request: https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/pull/764/files

My Fork: https://github.com/lmcarreiro/bootstrap-multiselect

Comment: Thanks, but what is the next step? Do we need to wait until the product owner accept your proposal?

Comment: BTW "onDeselectAll" - does not exist. And Documentation does not promise to trigger "onSelectAll" when deselecting. That is why I'm not sure if it is a bug or not.

Comment: @YevgeniyAfanasyev you can wait until the product owner accept my proposal, or you can get the version with this correction on my fork (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lmcarreiro/bootstrap-multiselect/f7e05ad4d78d414335c0a157ba6ab61edf3227f7/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js), but it's  not an official version...

Comment: The onDeselectAll event doesn't exist in the documentation, but in the code it exists. If you find for "onDeselectAll" in the js file, you will get a lot of occurences.

Comment: How do we know if your branch was merged into the project? Thank you for your explanation. For my current project I have to stick to official version. I hope the owner will accept your change soon.

Comment: If you've an github account, you can subscribe to receive notifications in my pull request, it's a button in the bottom-right corner of the page: https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/pull/764

Answer (score 0):

I added an `onchange` function to the HTML which counts how many options are selected and it is working:

```
<select id="yourID" class="custom-select" onchange="unselectAll();" multiple>
```

This is the function to verify that nothing is selected:

```
function unselectAll(){
    if($('#yourID :selected').length==0){
        //Do what you need here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yup this was a bug I encountered as well hence you can consider going for something like this

```
$(document).on('change','.multiselect',function(){
    var labels = [];
    var brands = $('#field option:selected');
    $(brands).each(function(index, brand){
        labels.push($(this).text());
    });
    var values = $("#field").val();
    if(values.length > 0){
        console.log(labels);
        console.log(values)
    }
})
```